# Very simple subscribe form for under construction page

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm setting up a Magento website and before it goes live I want to set up a under construction page.

I'd like to have people who are interested to subscribe and we'll send them out a email when the shop goes live.

I tried out bunch of these bigger PHP mailing/newsletter systems, but they were way to complicated and time consuming to get into because I need to work on other things.

So I'd like to know is there a easy way to do it myself or is there a script just for this task I haven't found yet? I also searched through few tutorial sites for what I was looking for, but I couldn't find anything useful. I really just need the bare minimum for this.

Thank you in advance, hopefully this question fits to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a simple form that lets users enter a name and email address.  Have the email addresses go straight into a database or some other form of storage (could be as simple as a text file).

Then, when ready, write a simple script that will send out an email to all the users in the database.

Answer (score 13):

use this in your page:

```
<!-- Subscription Form -->
<form action="form/form.php" method="post">
    <input name="email" class="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address ...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn_email">Send</button>
</form>
<!-- End Subscription Form -->
```

and this for form.php:

```
<?php
$to = "office@site.com";
$from = "no-reply@site.com";

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

$subject = "New subscription";
$body = "New user subscription: " . $_POST['email'];


if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
{ 
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-f " . $from))
    {
        echo 'Your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ') has been added to our mailing list!';
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
    }
}
else
{
   echo 'There was a problem with your e-mail (' . $_POST['email'] . ')';   
}
```

the above script will only send you an email with the new subscription, but you can extend it to do database insertion, subscriber confirmation, etc.  And also validate the data in the field where the subscriber enter the email.